# Preventing crawlers from reading underscore templates

Tags: templates, web-crawler, underscore.js, robots.txt

I need a robots.txt `Disallow` rule that prevents crawlers from following template tags like in `<script type="text/template">` tags.

When crawled, the url I get errors for looks like:

```
404 GET /foo/bar/<%=%20 getPublicUrl %20%
```

E.g.

```
<script type="text/template">
  <a href="<%= my_var %>" target="_blank">Test</a>
</script>
```

Blocked by something like:

```
Disallow: <%*%>
```

Any ideas?

I did notice that it seems to happen on anchors with `target="_blank"`. Not sure why that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit tricky.

Many crawlers, including Google, will silently URL-encode any unsafe characters in the URL before they check it against robots.txt. This means you have to block the encoded version.

For example, if the URL is:

```
http://example.com/foo/bar/<% my_var %>
```

The URL that Google actually checks against robots.txt will be:

```
http://example.com/foo/bar/%3C%%20my_var%20%%3E
```

The spaces and angle brackets are silently URL-encoded. So you need to block it like this:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: */%3C%*%%3E
```

If you try to block it like this:

```
# Does not work:
User-agent: *
Disallow: */<%*%>
```

then nothing will be blocked, because it's comparing "<" and ">" to "%3C" and "%3E".

I have verified that the above works for Google, but YMMV for other crawlers. Also note that some crawlers don't support wildcards at all.